# Rewriting multiple SQL commands into a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to turn this statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when year = ',
      year,
      ' then experience_rate end) AS `',
      year, '-Pen`'
    ) ORDER BY year
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT policy_number, primary_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM spooner_pec 
                   GROUP BY policy_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Into something like this:

```
SELECT policy_number, primary_name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('max(case when year = ', year, ' then experience_rate end) AS `', year, '-Pen`') ORDER BY year))
FROM spooner_pec 
GROUP BY policy_number
```

But as you can see by the fiddle, I am getting some strange output as a column instead of the actual columns, what am I doing wrong here?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1966c/5)

Comment: You are performing a dynamic pivot, so you have to build your SQL statement as a string and execute that dynamic SQL. You can't convert it into a static SQL statement. Unless it is OK for you to fix in that static SQL the years over which you group.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do regular expression search to get all the code in single line or selected code in single line.

Use find & replace

```
1. Under find section type "\n" --find all next line keywords
2. Under replace section type " " -- replace \n with one blank space
3. Tick "Use Regular Expression"
```

Your result will be in single line.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]
Replace with section is a blank space

*Note: This approach works on Windows platform and most of the editors.

Comment: Shrinking it down to 1 line is not really the issue, I must have a syntax error somewhere. I'm trying to turn multiple queries into a single query, not necessarily just make it all one line, maybe I should rephrase my question.